# how do you create a flashing word in pyhton 3. Like having STOP blink in a stop sign

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have to make the word STOP blink or flash in a stop sign.

I made the stop sign with turtle graphics, but can't figure out how to make the word stop blinking. It's an assignment for my class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code I did so far:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

t.color("black", "red")
t.begin_fill()
for count in range(8):
    t.forward(60)
    t.left(45)
t.forward(20)
t.end_fill()
t.color("black")
t.begin_fill()
t.right(90)
t.forward(180)
t.left(90)
t.forward(20)
t.left(90)
t.forward(180)
t.end_fill()
t.left(90)
t.forward(20)
t.color("white")
t.penup()
t.goto(-20, 40)
t.write("STOP", font=("Impact", 50))
t.goto(-30, -10)
```

Comment: Please add some code snippets of what you have tried in order for others to help you

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to add some code and explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35838811/3115244), you can achieve this by creating a separate Turtle object for writing the text and clearing it:

```
# create second turtle used for blinking text
eraseable = turtle.Turtle()
eraseable.color("white")
eraseable.hideturtle()
eraseable.up()
eraseable.setposition(t.position())
```

Which you can use like this to make the text blink once per second:

```
import time

# blink 20 times
for i in range(0,20):
    eraseable.write("STOP", font=("Impact", 50))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    eraseable.clear()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Full demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55672932

Comment: It's the `eraser` turtle whose color needs to be set. You can specify the color inside `erasableWrite()`. Update my code and demo accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than bring in another module like `import time`, and create lots of global turtles that won't get garbage collected, I'd use your existing turtle, once it's done it's drawing, and turtle's own `ontimer` events to animate the sign:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def blink_on():
    turtle.write("STOP", align="center", font=("Impact", 50))
    screen.ontimer(blink_off, 1000)

def blink_off():
    turtle.undo()
    screen.ontimer(blink_on, 1000)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.fillcolor("red")

turtle.begin_fill()
for _ in range(8):
    turtle.forward(60)
    turtle.left(45)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.forward(20)
turtle.right(90)

turtle.fillcolor("black")
turtle.begin_fill()
for _ in range(2):
    turtle.forward(180)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(20)
    turtle.left(90)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.pencolor("white")
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(30, 40)

screen = Screen()

blink_on()

screen.exitonclick()
```

One difference between this approach and @glhr's solution is that if you close the other solution's window while it's blinking, you'll get a dozen lines of error messages, due to out of sync events.  You shouldn't get any errors with this solution as its blinking is syncronous with turtle's event loop.